# how to delete scene?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollmagic

there's a code that creates the scene

```
function parallaxAuto() {
    var viewer       = document.querySelector('.viewer'),
    frame_count  = 6,
    offset_value = 500;

    // init controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: 0,
        reverse: true
      }
    });

    // build pinned scene
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#sticky',
      duration: (frame_count * offset_value) + 'px',
      reverse: true
    })
    .setPin('#sticky')
    //.addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

    // build step frame scene
    for (var i = 1, l = frame_count; i <= l; i++) {
      var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: '#sticky',
          offset: i * offset_value
        })
        .setClassToggle(viewer, 'frame' + i)
        //.addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
    }
}
```

I can not figure out how by clicking on the button to delete the scene.
I tried here in ways:

```
$('.left_arrr').click(function(event) {
        controller.destroy(reset);
        controller = null;
        scene.destroy(reset);
        scene = null;
    });
```

We need this in order that there will still be a slider of the three blocks.

Comment: can you post a fiddle? also please write the name of the library you're using

Comment: I just saw the library and they have this `controller.removeScene(Scene)` to remove one or more scene(s) from the controller.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fnethLxm/1/ @Khaled Al-Ansari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#destroy) you should pass a `boolean` value and your `reset` value got nothing in it from what I see!

```
scene = scene.destroy(true);
scene = null;
# Also the controller
controller.destroy(true);
controller = null;
```

This is what you should use.

Also there a good example on the scrollmagic website, [check it out](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/expert/removing_and_destroying.html)

Comment: position: fixed removed .. but the scene continues to operate ( @Khaled Al-Ansari

Comment: But the truck animation will stop! I guess that's what you want right?

Comment: I added this code controller.destroy(true); controller = null; and it worked. Thank you !!

Comment: and tell me how it is now all add to the slider? @Khaled Al-Ansari

Comment: what slider? @АлександрКотов